# "will likely have cut" usage correct?

Tags: verbs

from the news report

*xx will likely have cut yy jobs by end of fiscal 2012, the company has said.*

why use ***will have cut*** here?  I think "will cut" will be ok.

Comment: Use of the perfect construction as well as _will_ simply means that xx will likely be finished cutting yy jobs by the end of the year. It also leaves the impression that this is a minimum and there may be more cuts later, or possibly in the works now. Simple use of _will_, on the other hand, indicates **only** that xx plans to cut yy jobs by the end of the year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because some of those cuts might have already happened, or might be happening now.

As an example that's perhaps closer to home: if I write "I will have lost 2 stone by September 15th", I don't mean that I'm going to lose 2 stone in the next 5 days. I mean that, in 5 days, the sentence "I have lost 2 stone" will apply.

Comment: I believe both this and the distinction made in John Lawler's comment are valid reasons for choosing one form over another in different contexts.